# How do you summon a zombie on a zombie horse?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

What is the command to summon a zombie on a zombie horse?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *single* command to accomplish this task in Bedrock Edition <sub>*[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JogRT.png)*</sub>. However, with that in mind, it *can* be done with *multiple* commands.

***Note**: This answer assumes you're aware of how the [summon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/summon) and [ride](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/ride) commands work.*

---

##### Summoning Jockeys

The summon command can only be used to [summon specific jockeys](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Summoning_jockeys) <sub>*[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JogRT.png)*</sub> which does not include a zombie jockey:

> Only some jockeys can be summoned via commands: Skeleton Trap and a Ravager being rode by an Evoker, Pillager or a Vindicator.

<sub>***Note**: This quote has been paraphrased for the sake of brevity. For more complete information, please check the [wiki article on summoning jockeys](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Summoning_jockeys).*</sub>

##### Break it Down

To accomplish your desired result, you'll need to summon a zombie horse, followed by a zombie, then finally execute a ride command targeted at the two:

```
summon zombie_horse
summon zombie
ride @e[type=zombie,r=5] start_riding @e[type=zombie_horse,r=5] teleport_rider
```

[image: Screenshot of the results of the command.]

---

<sub>***1**: As of 20 SEP 2021.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry but this doesn't work in bedrock edition. In Java it would be `/summon zombie_horse ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:zombie}]}` but you can't use this command in bedrock.

See this links for more:

- [Reddit/using Java commands in bedrock](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/c84gtm/using_commands_in_bedrock_edition/)
- [Minecraft Fandom/summon jockeys](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Summoning_jockeys#Bedrock_Edition)
- [Minecraft command generators](https://www.digminecraft.com/generators/index.php)

> Again I'm sorry that there is no way to do this but I hope, I could help you with the links
> If you find an answer please create an answer and describe you way you did it to help others.
> Anyway, if my answer is useful for you, please mark this answer as accepted

**Have a great day!**

Answer (score -1):

In mcpe jockeys are created through events with /summon or /event(check wiki for advanced and updated help, but just put it after the entity specifier) , as these events only allow for vanilla jockeys this can't exist. I will update if find an addon solution or if this is changed

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! I'm not sure what pocket edition has to do with the author's question since they only explicitly point out that they're using [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition]. I recommend removal of that reference, and perhaps try adding details about the commands you mention to improve your post for future readers.